# Don't share custom taxonomy terms if applied to multiple Custom Post Types

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I have multiple Custom Post Types, named 'Companion', 'Digital', etc. I also have custom taxonomies named `issueDigital`, `issueCompanion`, etc.. I separated them out in the beginning, rather than using ONE `issue` taxonomy and applying them to all CPTs, simply because the data was shared between all CPTs. Issues from Digital would show up under Companion, and so on.

My quick fix was to separate them out, but now that I am nearing the end of the project I want to revisit this problem and create **one custom taxonomy which is applied to multiple CPTs but doesn't share data with each other**. I am most grateful for any input.

I've only found [this](https://www.skyverge.com/blog/dont-share-terms-between-wordpress-taxonomies/) which isn't ideal because you have to remember the following:

> One simple way to stop the records from being shared is to make the
>   admin user define a unique slug for each term that shares a common
>   name with another taxonomical term, ie: ‘Red’, ‘red’ in taxonomy ‘A’
>   and ‘Red’, ‘red-2’ in taxonomy ‘B’, etc. Obviously the drawback is
>   that you have to remember to do this, have to remember how many
>   different ‘red’ terms there are, all easy stuff to forget until it’s
>   too late.

Comment: What would you get out of this that you're not getting by having separate taxonomies? The solution to wanting two taxonomies that don't share data is to have two taxonomies, which you've done.

Comment: I have several different Post Types (companion, digital, etc) which represent magazine publications. Authors from one magazine might not actively publish articles in other magazines. So keeping the authors separate would be super helpful because eventually the list will get quite long

Comment: Your question doesn't mention authors? I thought you were asking about taxonomies?